# Fast and memory efficient binary matrix creation

Tags: matrix, permutation, combinations, combinatorics, sparse-matrix

I'm facing troubles while trying to solve a problem that is a harder nut to me than I assumed. Given a binary matrix of NxM, I want to generate all possible solution under the constraint that each column has exactly a single "1". For 2x3, that would be:

```
1 1
0 0
0 0

1 0
0 1
0 0

1 0
0 0
0 1

0 1
1 0
0 0

0 0
1 1
0 0

0 0
1 0
0 1

0 1
0 0
1 0

0 0
0 1
1 0

0 0
0 0
1 1
```

After some headaches, I have a recursive algorithm in C working, but I'm not too sure if it is correct as it obviously wasn't working for the longest time, missing some combinations. After changing the recursion at least the number of combinations is correct and for N x M that I can manually check it seems correct.

But: The memory consumption is terrible as I start with

```
1 1
0 0
0 0
```

and the rightmost column, setting the 1 to a 0 and the 0 in the line below to a 1, if there is any line. Then I go one column to the left (resetting what I've done to the rightmost column, like considering a carry) and iterate the position of the 1, and for each iteration I recurse to the right again until no column is left to iterate its 1. This approach may seem awkward to you (the code does to me), but I've though of it like counting in a polyad system, where the columns are digits and the position of the 1 gives the value of the digit.

Maybe it's just my broken way of recursing down, but currently I have to copy the current array for each recursion, which is of course terrible, but the only way I found yet, as having e.g.

```
0 1
1 0
0 0
```

and copying it twice for generating

```
0 0
1 1
0 0
```

and

```
0 0
1 0
0 1
```

indepently from each other is easier. But freeing memory in C while recursing down doesn't seem to fit my level of experience. I've done a rewrite in Java hoping the GC may help me out (can't believe it, but it looks like it does) but there again, the profiling says of course that copying the data is eating 99% of the cycles.

Do you have any suggestions for my problem? Is there maybe even a name for that, not to think of existing algorithms? Do you have pseudo code for the recursion at hand? Thanks a lot from a smoking brain!

I'm not even sure if this is a combinatoric or permutational problem.

Comment: Maybe I have missinterpreted your question, but wouldn't it be easier to handle the row in which the 1 is placed instead of passing along an entire matrix, and then printing output based on this?

Comment: Also, my instincts tell me that recursion is not the way to go - the subproblems do not depend at all on the previous results and vice versa, the problem is basic iteration, and as you rightly observed, it's equivalent to counting in an M-ary number system with N digits: This is iteration!

Comment: Added the tag [sparse-matrix] as that is what this process is creating.

Comment: Okay, I've solved this but in a completely different way, although using sparse matrices. But I'm creating them by counting binary, I know how many combinations there are, an starting with an array of zeros, I'm adding 1 in a loop. The carry handling is easily done in a while loop and voila.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just from verbalizing my thoughts in the comments to your question, I think your problem can be boiled down to some very simple iteration that basically won't use any memory at all:

From knowing that what you are doing is simple counting, we can design an iterative approach. If you have, like in your example a 2x3 matrix, it's equivalent to counting in a ternary number system with 2 digits. This means the largest value we can represent is 3^2 - 1 = 8.

This means we are going to count from 0 to 8. Now convert to ternary, like you would write a number to binary by hand. How many 3^1's are there in, say, 7? 2! So the position of the leftmost 1 in your matrix is row 2 (indexing from 0). Subtract 3x2 = 6 from the number we're converting, leaving 1. How many 3^0's are there? 1! So the 1 in the rightmost column is in row 1.

From this we have enough information to print the solution, and by doing it for all numbers from 0 to M^N - 1, you have all your solutions!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward, without any "clever" math tricks.

First, one standard method of representing sparse matrices is known as a [coordinate list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29): (index_row, index_column, value), for the non-zero entries.

Second, your setup is pretty basic: your values are all 1. [So, you need only store (ix_row, ix_col).]

Third: It gets easier: you have just one row per column.  So, for a given matrix, of size N x P (rows x columns), we can assume that there are P entries.  Let's just assume that the coordinate list for a given matrix has 1:P for the  index_column entries, and value = 1, for all entries. [I.e. the "full" coordinate list would be: (ix_row(1), 1, 1), (ix_row(2), 2, 1), ... , (ix_row(P), P, 1)].

Therefore, in filling the coordinate list, the problem is to create all possible row indices, which is simply sampling from 1:N, P times, *with replacement*.  You have N choices for the row for each and every row in the coordinate list.  The # of matrices is N^P.

Creating a list of all (1:N) x (1:N) x ... x (1:N) vectors is pretty easy: start at (1, 1, 1, ...., 1) and count up, in the last element, to (1, 1, 1, ..., N) and move over one step at a time.

This will generate all necessary coordinate lists to describe all of the matrices.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure if I get it and it is really what I need. It looks to me like after moving over (to the left), all the elements at the right will be fixed to N, loosing a lot of possibilities. Or do I get it wrong?

Hm, maybe you mean to have P (?) vectors of (1, 1, ..., 1)?

Comment: It isn't fixed at N: You start over.  E.g. for N=3, P=2: (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3).  It is much like counting in binary or decimal (like an odometer), and can be implemented in a P-depth recursion.

Comment: Okay, somehow I understood that your approach works without recursion. Is the recursion memory efficient in terms of that a single vector over which I'd recurse is sufficient? I want to experiment with values of N and P where N^P is kind of big.

Comment: You can do it with or without recursion.  All you need is the ability to store a P-long sequence (aka "array" or "vector") relating to the previous matrix, as these can be generated sequentially.  I would keep it simple and store the row indices as a vector, i.e. the 1st column from the coordinate list of a given matrix.  It can't really get much more memory efficient.  Still it would be trivial to iterate over, say, N = 4 billion x P = 4 billion within 16GB of RAM. (4 bytes for N, 4 billion values...).  Are your N and P that big?

Comment: (Continued) By the way, should you want to produce all such matrices, the number of unique matrices is N^P.  For N = P = 4B, this will not complete for a while, no matter what storage or generating mechanism you create.  :)